# what is the best way to have a SQL that only looks at MAX of a date field

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to query a table where one column is run_date.  I want to only retrieve results where run_date is the latest run_date in run_date column.  is it possible to have a dynamic query like this.  something like:

```
Select * from Order where DateUpdated = Max(DateUpdated)
```

Comment: You may list the data and ORDER BY DateUpdated DESC. IT gives you the newest record on top.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will return you all results with the latest DateUpdated.

```
Select *
  from Order
 where DateUpdated = (SELECT Max(DateUpdated)
                        FROM Order )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need the most recent row:

```
select top 1 *
from Order
order by DateUpdated desc
```

If you need to retrieve all the rows that correspond to the most recent date, then you can do this efficiently with CTE:

```
with cte
as
(
    select *, rank() over(order by DateUpdated desc) RankNumber
    from [Order]
)
select *
from cte
where RankNumber = 1
```

Assuming MS SQL 2005 or higher.

If you use SQL 2000, then use zerkms has the answer.

Comment: What if there are several records with the same date?

Comment: @zerkms - I thought that the most recent row is needed.

Comment: @Alex Aza: "I want to only retrieve result_S_"

Comment: @Alex Aza: probably, but I don't believe it does in this case.

Comment: Btw, curious what execution plan will be for your second advice. Nested fullscan query + outer fullscan query or something more performant

Comment: @zerkms - cte is more efficient, if there are no indexes than it will be just one scan, not two.

Comment: @Alex Aza: more efficient than what? `If there are no indexes` -- then it is a time to fire DBA

Comment: @zerkms - lol. More efficient than the query from your answer :).

Comment: @Alex Aza: only in cases when there are no indexes (omg, who could suppose that?)

Comment: @Alex Aza: If you're insisting on being pedantic - then *your* query returns different result than mine. Perhaps this could be an issue in some specific cases. Can you rewrite to return **the same set of fields**? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms - yes, if I know table structure. You are not going to use `*` in production code, are you? :)

Comment: @zerkms: Rank includes ties; row_number is without ties (arbitrary choice from tie). Moreover, at least on Postgres, your subquery version is much faster than this CTE version.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
Select * from Order where DateUpdated = (select Max(DateUpdated) from Order)
```